# User Interface Design in Android

Tags: android

I want to design the layouts programatically that means without the xml file as per project requirement.
But the terms used programatically is completely different from xml file.Is their any useful tutorial to learn programatically that means without xml file. guide me!

Comment: Try to search in google that [How to create a layout programatically](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+create+layout+programatically&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)

Comment: i tried it ,, but it not having complete guidance,,

Comment: be more specific and what you are looking for. as you saw, there are many tutorials out there.

Comment: [Have you tried this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/programmatically-create-layout-and-view.html)

Comment: Exactly what i need is, if we using xml file for a layout it is easy to see all the properties for every controls(controls such as text vew , edit view etc,,) but programatically it is very difficult to learn all the properties for controls . thats y im asking for tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create any view you want

- a linear layout

  ```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  ```
- A Text View

  ```
  final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF00FF);
      tv.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
      tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
      tv.setText("Where is Fred?");
      tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  ```

and anything else.

[Source](http://mainerrors.blogspot.in/2011/02/programmatically-creating-layout-part-1.html)

Comment: i have another small query ,, for text color,set background colors u mention like 0xFFFF00FF . what is the format(Hexadecimal format like that) of this color and how many colors availabe for this format and how to find all color code like 0xFF000000

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to spend some time learning about the `View` class and its popular subclasses such as `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, and so on. (Also, spend a bit of time looking at `Drawables`.)

When you're creating a layout using XML, you're using XML to define a hierarchy of `View` objects which, at runtime, are "inflated" into a *real* hierarchy of `View` objects that the XML layout file describes. For example, your first XML layout file might be a simple `LinearLayout` that contains a `TextView` (note I'm simplifying it for brevity):

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your `Activity` you would use this layout using `setContentView()`.

All that XML file is doing is providing a *specification*, if you like, about the `View` structure that the system needs to build (or *inflate*) for you. The end result is that there will be a real `LinearLayout` object (which is a subclass of `View`) that has a reference a child `TextView` (again a subclass of `View`) together with suitable layout parameters.

To do the above programmatically (i.e. by creating instances of objects and using their methods, rather than inflating from XML) you might do something like (again simplified):

```
LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("hello");
container.addChild(tv);  // Simple example - usually you'd specify layout parameters
setContentView(container);
```

The basic point I'm making is that, in really simple terms, a layout XML file can be thought of as a kind of 'script' that you can use to tell the system how to create a hierarchy of `Views`. You can create exactly the same result by programmatically creating instances of `View` objects and calling appropriate methods on them. Whichever route you take, the end result is the same: a bunch of `View` objects in memory that represent a View hierarchy.

What you will find is that XML layout attribute names aren't necessarily the same as the corresponding method names, but you can use the relevant API documentation to see what corresponding XML attribute strings are for given methods. For instance, the API documentation for `LinearLayout` details all of the methods as well as the XML attributes.